# Помогите с кнопкой "назад" в слайдере на js

Tags: javascript, слайдер, карусель

Делаю слайдер с кнопками <назад вперед>. кнопка вперед работает, все хорошо. Не знаю как написать функцию для кнопки назад. Сильно не ругайтесь, новичок(если честно до джавы еще не добрался, только html/css).

````
```
<a class="prev" >&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" >&#10095;</a>
 ```
````

```
let sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');

for (let i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
  init_slider(sliders[i]);
}

function init_slider(slider) {
  let slide = slider.querySelectorAll('.slide');
  
  let next = slider.querySelector('.next');
  
  let i = 0;
  
  next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    slide[i].classList.remove('block');
    
    i = (i + 1) % slide.length; // (*1)
    
    slide[i].classList.add('block');
  });
```

Comment: в вопросе отутсвует вопрос, как помочь? что не работает? что пытались сделать?

Comment: Будьте добры, загляните [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: в общем слайдер, с двумя кнопками. на кнопку вперед функция есть, она работает. на кнопку назад как написать функцию не понимаю.

Comment: попробуйте написать событие клик для prev только вместо `i = (i + 1) % slide.length; ` сделать `i = (i - 1) % slide.length; `

Comment: не получается, точнее я что-то не правильно делаю)
        
```let prev = slider.querySelector('.prev');
 
  prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
    slide[i].classList.remove('block');
    
    i = (i - 1) % slide.length; 
    
    slide[i].classList.add('block');
  }); ```